# TFS API: Find all test suites for a certain test case

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

I'm looking for a TFS API request to fetch all test suites (ids) that contains a certain test case.

Using the example form the TFS API page:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/suites

https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/test/suites?testCaseId=341&api-version=2.0-preview

... I get the response: 404 Page not found
(filled with my server and project etc.)

Is the example by Microsoft wrong?
Or is there another way to get all suites for a test case (not using the .NET way)?

Comment: Could you access TFS collection in the browser using the following URL:https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection with the account running rest api?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

You need to use the url without {project}. Seems the sample in the link is also lacking {project}

`GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollectio‌​n/_apis/test/suites?‌​testCaseId=341&api-v‌​ersion=2.0-preview`

However the API is including the project. Not sure if it's a content issue. Will double confirm and update to you.

---

Since the error is 404 Page not found, please double check if you are using the wrong url(such as with an extra space). Try to change a test case ID, double confirm there are test suits under the test case. You could also use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) to give a test with the API.

Comment: Yes, I use Postman for those tests ;-) ... The problem is the {project}. Its wrong to use it here (instead at other API requests) ... correct working url is: https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/test etc.

Comment: @Konrad Got the same result as you. Seems the sample in the link is also  lacking {project} , `GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/test/suites?testCaseId=341&api-version=2.0-preview` Not sure if it's a content issue. Will double confirm and update to you.